# Iphone apps communication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, communication

I want to create two iPhone apps: server+client (for once iphone).
Server will contain some data and client will asking for it sometime.
How I can to organize communication between them?
For example anybody knows how TextExpander works?

Regards,

Andrey Mirzoyan.

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, a good starting point would probably be the [Bonjour Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i) docs as it would provide a means of broadcasting/listening to see what clients are currently available.

There's also some sample code associated with the [NSNetService class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs that might prove very useful and at least provide some good pointers as to where to look next.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for use on one phone, then the only inter-application communication method that will work within a single stock OS iOS device is to have each app register a custom URL scheme, and have each app (re)launch the other app using these custom URL launches for communication, back-and-forth.

The URL scheme will contain a prefix.  The suffix of the URL can contain the data of the request or reply, if appropriately encoded.